# Java Date parsing fail

Tags: java, date

When I was trying to parse date in Java, both of these line return **`PhaseException`**, double-checked and doesn't know what' going on, please help!

```
Date dateobj = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse("Nov 12, 1994");
Date timeobj = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").parse("8:20 pm");
```

The full trace:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Nov 12, 1994"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at testTime.main(testTime.java:12)
```

Comment: [Are you catching or declaring that exception to be thrown?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)

Comment: @Makoto no, it is a exception declared by Java

Comment: PhaseException is not a standard Java exception. Post the full stack trace. Also, check that your Locale is English. All languages don't call November November.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you code doesnot produces any Exception but still it is always safe to specify the Locale

Like this

```
Date dateobj = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                                          .parse("Nov 12, 1994");
Date timeobj = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                                     .parse("8:20 pm");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Double check the declared `throws`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) for `DateFormat#parse`.  It is throwing what's known as a [checked exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html); this means that even though this exception occurs, you should be able to recover from it.

You **must** either:

- Declare it to be thrown (add `throws ParseException` at the signature of your method), or
- Wrap the expression in a `try...catch` block.  An example is below.

  ```
  Date dateobj = null;
  Date timeobj = null;
  try {
      dateobj = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse("Nov 12, 1994");
      timeobj = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").parse("8:20 PM");
  } catch(ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

As it stands with your snippet, if I take either precaution (declaring it to be thrown or catch it myself), then I encounter no further runtime errors.

Comment: That's what I got
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Nov 12, 1994"

 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)

 at testTime.main(testTime.java:12)

Comment: Funny; I put your code into my IDE and I don't get that exception.  That is, after I make sure to handle the exception properly.

Comment: I'm using Java 7. Did you try to use the above code in your program?

Comment: Yes, I use Eclipse with Java 7, your code gives the error msg listed in the main thread

Comment: I'm 100% convinced that it's something else, then.  If you create a `main` method with only that block of code in it, then it should compile just fine.

Comment: Read my comment. In your locale, November is not called November. DateFormat uses your locale by default. Set its locale to English if you want to parse an English date.

Comment: sorry that I missed your comment, it works, you are the boss, JB!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JB Nizet, this error is caused by a different locale setting, adding locale to the simpledateformat works